# Calling method on object in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Why can't I call methods directly on my object in CodeIgniter?

For example:

```
$campaign = $this->Campaign_model->get_campaign_from_id($campaign_id);
$campaign->load_settings(); // returns error: Call to undefined method stdClass::load_settings()
```

The Campaign object is correctly created, but I can't call methods on it even if it's within the class.

Here is my Campaign_model method I'm calling:

```
function load_settings()
{
    echo "test";
    exit;
}
```

How can I do this kind of operations then? I think I was respecting basic object logic, but I can't make it work.

Comment: What does `get_campaign_from_id` return?  It seems it's returning `stdClass`, which makes me think it's DB results.  I think you want `$this->Campaign_model->load_settings()`.

Comment: But if I have a few objects, I call `$this->Campaign_model->load_settings()`, on which object this call would apply? I need to make the request on a specific object. How to make sure it will be called on the object I want this way?

Comment: CodeIgniter models are just a collection of functions, there is only ever one instance of each model.  You don't return "model objects", that's not how it works.  What are you returning from `get_campaign_from_id` and what should `load_settings` actually do?

Comment: Oh, I see, that's disapointing. Is there a way I can call a function for an object then, that allows me to change the object itself? Like passing it in paramater, work on it, and return the new object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter models are just a collection of functions, there is only ever one instance of each model. You don't return "model objects", that's not how it works.

The "object" you are returning from `get_campaign_from_id` is just a normal PHP object and has *nothing* to do with your model.

You can't call functions on `stdClass` objects, but you can pass it to a function that can edit its properties.

```
// in PHP5 objects are automatically passed by reference
function load_settings($obj){
    $obj->test = '123';  // edit a property on the object
}
```

Comment: And it would be called this way? `$this->Campaign_model->load_settings($obj)`?